# Arcpy Select by attributes IN operator with Tuple

Tags: arcpy, sql, select-by-attribute

I have two layers 1. Buffer zones with a string ID 
2. the same buffer zones with the String ID plus an extra field call it zone B

*this process is taking place within a loop already, just to give some scope

Objective - extract all of the first layers buffer ID's and use a select by attributes QRY on the second layer to select the first layer zones that are only labeled zone B

What I have done so far:

-extract ID's from first layer store it in a list then tuple

```
Zonelist = []
for x in gp.SearchCursor(layer1):
    ID = x.ID
    Zonelist.append(ID)
ZoneTuple = tuple(Zonelist)
```

now I want to construct a QRY for layer2 that selects all the ID's in the tuple and equal zone b

*I am storing the ID's into a tuple to emulate the parenthesis SQL syntax when using the IN operator within Arcmap

```
layer2QRY = "ID IN {} AND Labelr = 'ZoneB'".format(ZoneTuple)

layer2 = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Allzones, "layer2select", layer2QRY)
```

Update: the QRY works when there are multiple ID's in the tuple. However when there is only one ID in the tuple ex. ('4321',) a comma appears after the one object and it throws an execute error

Comment: For a start, first, I'd move ZoneTuple = tuple(ZoneList) out of the for loop. All you're doing as is is rebuilding it each time. Second, you need a space in your query format after IN.

Comment: okay made your changes now I am getting an execute error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's not working, take it back a step and print your`layer2QRY` to see what is being passed to your `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management()` - you'll see it's currently trying to query literally on

```
"ID IN " + ZoneTuple + " AND " + "Labelr="+"'ZoneB'"
```

whereas you want it to query on

```
ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) AND Labelr = 'ZoneB'
```

Once you get your query to print like the above, then you can add it back into your MakeFeatureLayer.

```
Zonelist = []
for x in arcpy.SearchCursor(layer1):
    ID = x.ObjectID
    Zonelist.append(ID)

ZoneTuple = tuple(Zonelist)

layer2QRY = """ ID IN {} AND Labelr = 'ZoneB' """.format(ZoneTuple)

print layer2QRY  # Added to test layer2QRY

layer2 = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Allzones, "layer2select", layer2QRY)
```

---

Update for if there is only one feature - this checks number of IDs in the list, and constructs a fake tuple without the comma based on the only ID in the list.

```
Zonelist = []
for x in arcpy.SearchCursor(layer1):
    ID = x.ObjectID
    Zonelist.append(ID)

if len(Zonelist) == 1:
    ZoneTuple = "({})".format(Zonelist[0])
else:
    ZoneTuple = tuple(Zonelist)
```

Comment: you've answered a bunch of my questions Midavalo, thanks!

Comment: also why does a comma get added to a tuple containing one item?

Comment: see [Why does adding a trailing comma after a variable name make it a tuple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750632/why-does-adding-a-trailing-comma-after-a-variable-name-make-it-a-tuple)

Answer (score 3):

You've got some weird quoting going on.
I find it helpful to print out the query being used in cases like this.

In your case, the value of `layer2QRY` is literally:

```
' "ID IN " + ZoneTuple + " AND " + "Labelr="+"\'ZoneB\'" '
```

You've used triple quotes, which means everything between them is a string literal.

Your first attempt may have been closer to correct, but instead of using string arithmetic to build strings, it's usually better to use the `format` function. This is probably what you were trying to do:

```
layer2QRY = "ID IN {0} AND Labelr='ZoneB'".format(str(ZoneTuple))
```

Comment: figured out the formatting right before you answered this. check my update for the question now!